# Google spreadsheet throws an error when run the script from a shared spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have shared a Google spreadsheet with my friend with a button that will run a Google script when clicked. It works fine when I click the button, however, it throws an error "Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document." when he clicks. I have given him the normal permission to access and edit the spreadsheet. I do not know if there are any other permissions I have to give him to run the script.
He has also allowed the permission to run the script.
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Try having your friend go into the code editor and try running the function and authorizing the script

Comment: In addition to Cooper's comment, do make sure that your friend has access to _all_ of the files, if there are more than one, that the script accesses when executed. It would also help if you can provide your code and specify which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Thank you all for your insightful comments. After seeing Cooper's comment I had my friend run the script and realized that the issue was with a variable initialization with a sheet id, 'var sheetId = 'zzzzzzzzzzEkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs';' to which he has no access. To solve it, I tried the following code assuming he can access the file to write to it while running the script and then revok the sharing permission end of the script. But it didn't work either. Your comments helped identify the issue, can you help me fix the actual issue?

Comment: This is what I tried, DriveApp.getFileById('zzzzzzzzzzEkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs').setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

Comment: This is the error I get.

Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: `zzzzzzzzzzEkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs` doesn't look like a valid spreadsheet ID. You'd have to replace that with the [spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet) of the sheet the script is supposed to access. If the spreadsheet ID is the ID of the Sheets file the script is bound to, try using `var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();`

Comment: @DuuEyn In the script I have used the correct spreadsheet id.

Comment: I see. In that case, your only option is to manually share the file to your friend. `DriveApp` can only modify the permissions of the file the user already owns or already has edit permissions to before running the script.